# Add events to controls that were added dynamically

Tags: c#

I am working on a winforms app and I have added some controls dynamically (eg. `Button`). I want to add an event to that created button; how can I perform this? Also, can someone refer a `C#` book to me which covers all winforms topics?

Comment: Books: I liked C# in a nutshell, but I think any C# book covers this.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
// create some dynamic button
Button b = new Button();
// assign some event to it
b.Click += (sender, e) => 
{
    MessageBox.Show("the button was clicked");
};
// add the button to the form
Controls.Add(b);
```

Comment: thanks please explain '+=' and '=>' more or give me a link where i can read more about it.

Comment: The `+=` operator assigns a handler to an event. You should [read about events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739.aspx).

Comment: The `=>` indicates a lambda expression. You should [read about lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) and [anonymous methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx).

Answer (score 20):

I totally agree with Darin's answer, and this is another syntax of adding dynamic event

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button b = new Button();
    b.Click += new EventHandler(ShowMessage);
    Controls.Add(b);
}

private void ShowMessage(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Message");
}
```

Comment: How can we access properties of `b` inside `ShowMessage` ?

Comment: @Sujoy Parameter sender is Button. Just cast sender to Button and then you can reach properties.

Comment: @Serken apologies, I meant how can we access `b` from some other function. I guess we need to name the button after adding it so that we can access it later.

Comment: @Sujoy What about keeping Button as a Global variable ?

Comment: @Serken, it is not feasible that way. What if I create 100 buttons, I would need 100 global variables. I figured that instead of creating global variables we need to name the button to access it later.