# Addhandler for dynamically created controls

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I've written a piece of code that retrieves the number of photo albums a person has and then dynamically creates the same amount of ImageButtons within the 'AlbumsPanel' panel.

I have given Each ImageButton a unique Id (Grabs AlbumId from Albums table within sql server) and would like to be able to identify which ImageButton the user clicks (Store the myAlbum.ID in a variable some how so it can be used in a later stored procedure to retrieve pictures that belongs to that album).

spRetrieveAlbums example code:

```
    SELECT AlbumId FROM dbo.Albums WHERE Id = @CurrentUserId;
    SET @AlbumCount = @@ROWCOUNT;
```

Main.aspx.vb code:

```
    Connection.Open()

        sqlReader = spRetrieveAlbums.ExecuteReader()

            If sqlReader.HasRows() Then
                Do While sqlReader.Read()
                    Dim myAlbum = New ImageButton
                    myAlbum.ID = sqlReader.GetInt32(0)
                    myAlbum.Visible = True
                    myAlbum.Width = 160
                    myAlbum.Height = 160
                    myAlbum.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid
                    myAlbum.BorderColor = Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke
                    myAlbum.BorderWidth = 1
                    AlbumsPanel.Controls.Add(myAlbum)
                Loop
            End If

        sqlReader.Close()

        AlbumCount = spRetrieveAlbums.Parameters("@AlbumCount").Value

    Connection.Close()

        AlbumCountSpan.InnerHtml = "Albums: " & AlbumCount
```

Someone mentioned using an addhandler to the code but I'm not 100% sure how they work! Can someone point me in the right direction and give an example?

Comment: [this][1] could solve your problem, It already solved mine.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291077/add-events-to-controls-added-dynamically

Comment: @lmad VB.NET Syntax of events\delegate very different from C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in loop block:

```
AddHandler myAlbum.Click, AddressOf NameOfMethode
```

or separate metode each iteration, using lambda:

```
AddHandler myAlbum.Click, Sub() someAction
```

In the first way you should identify the sender. like:

```
Sub NameOfMethode(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs) 
   Label1.Text = Ctype(sender, ImageButton).ID
End Sub
```

but in the second way you can write Appropriate function for each iteration. like:

```
AddHandler myAlbum.Click, Sub() Label1.Text = sqlReader(0)
```

Comment: Thanks :) I'm still not 100% sure what you mean, could you please give an example using my code? I've posted my new code in the answer section

Comment: post also your the procedure you want Execute when every button clicked.

Comment: I've solved it thank you :) I used the following: AddHandler myAlbum.Click, Sub() AlbumClick(myAlbum.ID) and Protected Sub AlbumClick(ByVal e As Object)
        MsgBox(e)
    End Sub