# C# Override method like in lua

Tags: c#, lua

So in lua you can do something like this:

```
local button = CreateButton()
button:SetText("hello world")
button:SetPos(150, 20)
button.DoClick = function() 
print("This button said hello")
end
```

Now I was wondering if you can do something like this in C#
Currently I have

```
Button button = new Button();
button.setPos(150, 20);
// Need something like button.DoClick here
```

Is there a way to accomplish what I want in C#?

Comment: What did you find in the documentation for `Button` around how to handle the click event, and how did it fail to answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Use a C# delegate.

in your case:

```
button.Click += ....
```

See for an example: [Add events to controls added dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291077/add-events-to-controls-added-dynamically)

For the other functions:

```
button.Text = "hello world";
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158234(v=vs.110).aspx

```
button.Location = new Point(150, 20);
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location(v=vs.110).aspx