# How to dynamically add events to a large number of controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, eventhandler

I'm trying to add **1152** small *pictureBoxes* to a *Winform* dynamically then I want to add to each of those pictureBoxes a *Click event* so that when I click on them, the image change. I have no idea how to add event handler!?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Image image1= Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\image1.png");
        Image image2= Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\image2.png");


        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                var pictures= new PictureBox
                {
                    Name = "pic" + i + j,
                    Size = new Size(14, 14),
                    Location = new Point(j * 14, i * 14),
                    Image = image1,
                };
                this.Controls.Add(pictures);
            }
         }
}
```

Comment: `pictures.Click += "{{youreventhandler}}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add events to controls added dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291077/add-events-to-controls-added-dynamically)

Comment: @SeM Thanks. It worked. But can you tell me how to change the image from that EventHandler?

Comment: Wait I will write it on answers, so it will be more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a sequence of PictureBoxes and you want two things:

- You want to subscribe to a Click event
- If the Click event occurs you want to change the image, probably depending on the picture box that was clicked.

First you need to have a sequence of the PictureBoxes you want to have this behaviour. If you don't have a sequence yet, and you want all PictureBoxes on a certain Control to have this behaviour you could use this:

```
IEnumerable<PictureBox> GetPictureBoxes(Control control)
{
     return control.Controls.OfType<PictureControl>();
}
```

See [Enumerable.OfType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Subscribe to event:

```
IEnumerable<PictureBox> myPictureBoxes = ... 
foreach (PictureBox pictureBox in myPictureBoxes)
{
    pictureBox.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox_Click);
}
```

Event handler:

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox pictureBox = (PictureBox)sender;

    Image imageToShow = DecideWhichImageToShow(pictureBox); // TODO
    // change the image:
    pictureBox.Image = imageToShow
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On event handler's method, the `sender` argument will be your `PictureBox` object, so you can write something like this:

```
private void Pb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox pb = sender as PictureBox;
    try
    {
        if (pb != null)
            pb.Image = Image.FromFile(@"NewImagePath");

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```