# How to disable a button until a textbox is not empty in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I'm working with windows forms in C#. I need to enable a OK button after user filled a textbox.

My problem here, this mentioned textbox is creating in the runtime. It's not previously designed in the form.

For a previously designed textbox, textbox_textchanged event can be used to track the input value of textbox. But how to handle this situation ?

Comment: This 10 year old post answers your question: [Add events to controls added dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291077/add-events-to-controls-added-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

You can also attach the event handler in your code at the location where the textbox is created like this:

```
....

TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
textBox.TextChanged += textbox_textchanged;

...
```

and the event handler like:

```
private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox box = sender as TextBox;
    okButton.Enabled = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(box.Text);
}
```

Comment: How to do this for multiple text boxes that created dynamically

Comment: Depends on the logic of your application. Is there only one OK button which is to be enabled once all textboxes are filled, you can attach the same event handler to all textboxes, add the boxes to a private list 'myTextBoxes', and change the body of the event handler to okButton.Enabled = myBoxes.All(box => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(box.Text));

Answer (score 0):

You can add a delegate to dynamically created TextBox similarly as you add a delegate to statically added (at design time) textbox.

```
TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
txtBox.TextChanged += TextChangedHandler;
```

In your delegate `TextChangedHandler` access the `TextBox` from the `sender` parameter, like below

```
void TextChangedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var txtBox = sender as TextBox;
  var text = txtBox.Text;
}
```