# How to get the id of dynamically generated button when clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, button, event-handling

I am dynamically generating buttons based of text value stored in a SQL Server database table.

How to get the ID value associated with it to show in textbox.text when the button is clicked?

Here is my code

```
InitializeComponent();

Connection connection = new Connection();
connection.cn.Open();

SqlCommand cmm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Groups] WHERE Show_menu = 1 ORDER BY [Group_Name]", connection.cn);

using (SqlDataReader rd = cmm.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (rd.Read())
    {
        Button bt = new Button();

        //this is the buttons name but i also need the id associated with it to show in separated textbox when clicked

        bt.Text = (string)rd["Group_Name"].ToString();
        bt.Size = new Size(257, 57);
        bt.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#2E1E5B");
        bt.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 13f, FontStyle.Bold);
        bt.ForeColor = Color.White;
        bt.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        bt.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        // ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Your query is `SELECT *` so if there is an id in the table it ought to be in the query.  What is the problem?  Side note: you do not need to create a new unique `Font` object for each button.  Create one and use it over and over.

Comment: Your code doesn't look complete.  Inspect the `sender` parameter of the click event that you assign to each button's click event, cast it to a button, and key off the name or tag or text property that you need.

Comment: Perhaps [the following](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/dynamic-textboxs-csharp) might assist.

Comment: When I click a button I need to show it's ID in a textbox

Comment: @LarsTech can you explain in code please. I'm still a noob haha.

Comment: @Rawad You can refer to this tutorial: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Get-Value-Text-of-dynamically-created-TextBox-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean button `Name` property not `Id` because button do not have `Id` property.
You need to give button `Name` property, and do this

```
InitializeComponent();
Button bt = new Button();
bt.Name = "hello";
bt.Click += (sender, e) =>
{
   textBox1.Text = bt.Name;
};
Controls.Add(bt);
```

Ref: [Add events to controls that were added dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291077/add-events-to-controls-that-were-added-dynamically)