# How to change label text with double click event?

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I create as many dynamic labels as the user wants.

```
for (int j = 0; j < Nitelik_Counter; j++)
{
    Label labeltest= new Label();
    labeltest.Text = "N - " + j.ToString();
    labeltest.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    labeltest.Location = new Point(10 + j * 70, 10);
}
```

And I determine their text like `"N+i.toString()"` for default.
After that, I'm adding this to the form. I want to do is when the form is open and the user double-clicks one of the labels, a rename function will be open like in the Windows os, and when the user presses the enter it must be save. How do I do that?

Comment: Add `labeltest.DoubleClick += Labels_DoubleClick;` inside the loop. Then, create the `void Labels_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)` event handler method where you can cast `sender` into `Label` and manipulate it however you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add events to controls that were added dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291077/add-events-to-controls-that-were-added-dynamically)

Comment: Create a user control where you swap the label for a textbox when the user double clicks the label.  On keypress in the textbox check for the enter key and set the text to the label from the textbox at that time.  Then show the label and hide the textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create labels, setup DoubleClick handler like this:

```
// ...
Label labeltest= new Label();
labeltest.DoubleClick += Label_DoubleClick;
```

In the handler, you can add temporary TextBox to the form, place it over the original label, wait until the user presses Enter or Escape and then either change the original text or not and remove the textbox, like this:

```
protected void Label_DoubleClick(object? sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is Label label)
    {
        var box = new TextBox();
        box.Name = "TextField";
        box.Text = label.Text;
        box.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        box.AutoSize = false;
        box.Dock = DockStyle.None;
        box.Size = label.Size;
        box.Location = this.PointToClient(label.Parent.PointToScreen(label.Location));
        box.BackColor = BackColor;
        box.PreviewKeyDown += (a, b) => {
            if (b.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
            {
                box.Parent.Controls.Remove(box);
            }
            else if (b.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                label.Text = box.Text;
                box.Parent.Controls.Remove(box);
            }
        };
        box.LostFocus += (a, b) => { box.Parent?.Controls.Remove(box); };

        Controls.Add(box);
        Controls.SetChildIndex(box, 0);
        box.SelectAll();
        box.Focus();
    }
}
```